# problem with ledpar: "! Undefined control sequence. l.36 \ledRcolfalse"

Tags: ledmac

I am trying to produce a bilingual edition with Latin on the left and English on the right using ledmac and ledpar.  I cannot compile even the most minimal example as I receive the error message

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.36   \ledRcolfalse

Here is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar}

\listfiles

\lineation{page}
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}

\firstlinenum{5}
\linenumincrement{5}

\newcommand{\E}{\emph{E} }

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\textbf{$\slash$\E 47vB$\slash$} Tantum verum opponitur falso. Quaeritur de hoc sophismate.  Quod probatur sic.  Verum opponitur falso et nihil aliud quam verum opponitur falso, ergo tantum verum opponitur falso.  Et videtur ibi esse locus ab expositione vocabuli scilicet ab expositione huius dictionis `tantum'.  Improbatur sic.  \edtext{Contra.}{\Afootnote{\emph{Sic}.}}  Tantum verum opponitur falso, ergo tantum verum et falsum opponuntur.  Et videtur ibi esse locus a convertabili.  Probatio sequitur si verum opponitur falso, ergo verum et falsum opponuntur et e converso. Verum et falsum opponuntur, ergo verum opponitur falso.  Sicut sequitur Socrates et Plato sunt similes, ergo Sortes est similis Platoni, et e converso.  Unde ista relatio quae est oppositio fundatur supra ista duo extrema quae sunt verum et falsum.  Sicut a parte illa similitudo fundatur supra illos duos terminos qui sunt Sortes et Plato.  Convertuntur ergo ista verum opponitur falso.  Et verum et falsum opponuntur.  Igitur eodem addito utrobique adhuc convertentur.  Et sic addita hac dictione tantum.  Ad utrumque adhuc convertentur.  Et sic sequitur tantum verum opponitur falso, ergo tantum verum et falsum opponuntur et e converso.  Sit haec est falsa ut probabo tantum verum et falsum opponuntur.  Ergo et haec tantum verum opponitur falso.  Quod autem sit falsa patet quoniam si haec esset vera tantum verum et falsum opponuntur sequeretur quod nulla alia opponerentur.  Et sic sequeritur quod album et nigrum non opponerentur quod falsum est.  Igitur haec est falsa tantum verum et falsum opponentur, ergo et prima.  Haec scilicet tantum verum opponitur falso.  Igitur prima falsa.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\textbf{$\slash$\E 47vB$\slash$} Only true is opposed to false.  It is inquired concerning this sophism, which may be proved thus.  True is opposed to false and nothing other than true is opposed to false, therefore only true is opposed to false.  And here is seen to be a locus of the exposition of words namely from the exposition of this word `only'.  It is proved negatively thus.  Only true is opposed to false, therefore only true and false are opposible.  And here is seen to be a locus from conversion.  The proof follows if true is opposed to false, therefore true and false are opposed and conversely, true and false are opposed, therefore true is opposed to false. In the same way it follows Socrates and Plato are similar, therefore Socrates is similar to Plato, and conversely.  From which this relation, which is opposition, is established between those two extremes which are true and false, in the same way, partly, the former likeness is established between those two terms which are Socrates and Plato.  Therefore this is converted, `true is opposed to false', and `true and false are opposed'.  %Igitur eodem addito utrobique adhuc convertentur.  Et sic addita hac dictione tantum.  Ad utrumque adhuc convertentur.  Et sic sequitur tantum verum opponitur falso, ergo tantum verum et falsum opponuntur et e converso.  Sit haec est falsa ut probabo tantum verum et falsum opponuntur.  Ergo et haec tantum verum opponitur falso.  Quod autem sit falsa patet quoniam si haec esset vera tantum verum et falsum opponuntur sequeretur quod nulla alia opponerentur.  Et sic sequeritur quod album et nigrum non opponerentur quod falsum est.  Igitur haec est falsa tantum verum et falsum opponentur, ergo et prima.  Haec scilicet tantum verum opponitur falso.  Igitur prima falsa.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

I added the \listfiles command at Jon's suggestion, to see what version of ledmac/ledpar I'm using, and I get the error message before this information is provided:

```
[liana@athena anonymierfordensis]$ pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ngerman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibycus, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, portuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish, turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/latin.ldf
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf)) (./ledmac.sty (./ledpatch.sty)) (./ledpar.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.36   \ledRcolfalse
```

So I'm still not sure if it's the age of the packages that I'm using or what.

Comment: Sorry, but the only error I get is that `\E` is undefined: what's its definition?

Comment: Ack, sorry, I was too minimal; add this to the preamble:

\newcommand{\E}{\emph{E} }

Comment: Now I get no error (and no output either, because the `\Pages` command is missing).

Comment: `\ledRcolfalse` has to do with the 'Leftside' environment in `ledpar`.  It seems suspicious to me that you can get such an error if you load `ledpar`; and does `l.36 \ledRcolfalse`  come from the minimal example you posted?

Comment: Yes, the `l.26 \ledRcolfalse` error message is the one I get with the minimal example (in fact, I get it with every variation of a test example that I have tried to compile, including a stripped down version of the facing-pages example at [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ledmac/ledpar.pdf]).

Comment: @Sara -- OK, well `l.26` makes much more sense than `l.36`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference:

- New version(s) = 2012
- Old version = 2005

A possible answer: you have a mixed set of `ledpar` and `ledmac`.  (Or your system is loading a mixed set.)  I can replicate your error(s) if I use an old version of `ledmac` with a new version of `ledpar`.

In the old versions of the package, the `\newif\ifledRcol` line was in `ledpar` (line 32), while in the new versions it is in `ledmac` (line 134).

Your error line `l.36` relates to the new version of `ledpar`: that line reads: `\ledRcolfalse`.  But `*tex` can't find where this if-switch is defined because it is defined in the new version of `ledmac`, which either you don't have or your system can't find.

On a GNU/Linux system (and Macs, I guess), you can check which version your system finds by using the command `kpsewhere ledpar.sty` and `kpsewhere ledmac.sty`.  But note that if you have these files in the working directory, they will be the ones that are used (and `kpsewhere` will not find them!).  Obviously, it is wise to only have one version of these two files, and to make sure that they are from the same 'release'.

Comment: Success!  I did have the 2005 version of ledmac; I've gotten the new one, and I could compile.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Sara -- Glad it is solved!  It was a strange one.

Comment: @Sara: You can accept an answer by clicking on the (light) green check mark blow the number of upvotes. (@jon: +1 for your answer.)

Answer (score 4):

As egreg already wrote as comment: `\Pages` is missing.

After the end of the Left-/Right-Side-Double you need to say `\Pages` to inform the [`ledpar` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ledpar), that there is a pair of pages to be output:

```
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
```

i.e. after each `\end{Rightside}` place a `\Pages`. With `ledpar 2012/04/04 v0.10` and `ledmac 2012/04/04 v0.14` ([ledmac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ledmac)) I don't get an error in that case.

Edit: Since Monday there is an update available for ledpar/ledmac, see http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg04932.html. Maybe it is best to try those versions?

Comment: In the various test files I set up, I had versions with and without the \Pages command; it doesn't make a difference.  Even with this command, I still get the undefined control sequence error, apparently being triggered by "\ledRcolfalse".  I've tried blowing away the .aux files and doing a clean compile, and that does no good.

I'm guessing I've got an old version of ledmac/ledpar, so upgrading those is the next thing to try.

Comment: There is now even a newer version of both packages, please see my edited answer.

Comment: @Sara -- obviously, the `\Pages` command is not optional, so whatever files don't have it, put it in.  I also doubt the age of your versions of `ledmac` and `ledpar` are at issue.  I just compiled the file without error, and `\listfiles` gives me this in the `.log`: `ledmac.sty 2005/03/24 v0.7 LaTeX port of EDMAC` and `ledpar.sty 2005/04/08 v0.3b ledmac extension for parallel texts`.

Comment: @Jon, if you don't think it's the versions of the packages, do you have any suggestions for what the cause is?

Comment: @Sara -- It is worth checking the version and posting it in your question.  You can do this by adding `\listfiles` in the preamble; when you run (pdf)latex, it will write which versions you are using of the loaded packages.  (It just seems unlikely that you are using versions older than 2005.)

Comment: I added \listfiles, and tried to compile, and I get the error message before it lists which version of ledpar/ledmac I have.  I've edited my original post with the output, since it's too long to post as a comment.

Comment: @Sara -- I also doubt that your version of `ledpar` is the problem, but to be sure, you can always just find the file `ledpar.sty` on your system and check the version in `\ProvidesPackage`. Your minimal example compiles without problems on the afaik most recent version (2012/04/04).

Comment: @Florian -- Ahah!  Thanks for the `\ProvidesPackage` tip, I didn't know that.  Yup, I've got [2012/04/04 v0.10 ledmac extension for parallel texts].  So now I'm back to being completely stumped as to why all of you can compile this and I can't.

Comment: @Sara -- I think you need to hit `q` to get past the error and let the document finish as best it can.  (You can also put `\listfiles` before the documentclass.) Anyway, if you're having such trouble with `\ledRcolfalse` being undefined, what happens if you add `\newif\ifledRcol\ledRcolfalse` to your preamble after you load `ledpar`?

Comment: @Jon: Hitting `q` when I reach the first error causes me to exit compiling.  I've tried simply hitting enter, and then it does move on to further errors until eventually it hits a point where it gets stuck and simply won't go any further no matter how many times I hit enter.

I added the command you suggested, and I get the same error message at the same point in compilation.  However, this time hitting enter allows me to continue and cycle through a number of further errors until it reaches the \Pages command, when I get `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'hbox' defined.` and can't go further.

Comment: @Sara -- Hmm, I thought `q` was for 'quiet' and `x` was for 'exit' on all setups. How do you know this lastest error is due to the `\Pages` command?  Maybe you should delete all auxiliary files (all but the `.tex` one), run `latex` (or whichever variant you use), and then post the `.log` file somewhere where people can look at it (either here, if short enough, or somewhere where people can download it).  Your errors are very strange, to say the least.

Comment: @Sara -- One other thing, it seems that your actual TeX distribution is fairly old.  I don't run an up to date one myself (TeX Live 2009 on Ubuntu), but I have `LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>`, `Babel <v3.8l>` (= 2008), and `Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h`. (Compare your posted log above.)  It may be time to update your system in general, and independently of whether you get `ledpar` to work.